# How to accept whitespace in string method options

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, thor

I have an method that takes an string option containing whitespace:

```rb
desc 'events', 'List events'
method_option :since, :desc => 'Show events since', :default => "2 years ago"
def events
    # ...
end
```

but it seems that the parameters are naively split on whitespace so I get this error:

```
$ example events --since="1 hour ago"
ERROR: "example events" was called with arguments ["hour", "ago"]
Usage: "example events"
```

If I change the type to array I can get it to accept the full value, but that's not exactly what I'm after.

Any advice would be appreciated.

---

**Edit**

[@mrlew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41624031/117)'s answer demonstrated that my error wasn't a Thor issue, and it made me to go back and check my assumptions. I'm using the Thor CLI rather than Thor modules, and in my wrapper script I wasn't [handling args correctly](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#POSPARAMREF). I just needed to wrap `${@}` in double quotes, as below, and now everything works as expected.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ruby -Ilib ./exe/example "${@}"
```

Thanks @mrlew :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know thor gem very well, but this code just might work:

```
class Example < Thor
    desc 'events', 'List events'
    method_option :since, desc: 'Show events since', default: "2 years ago"
    def events
        puts "since: " + options[:since]
    end
end
```

Some points:

- `desc` first parameter must be the name of the method called. In your
  example, it was different.
- you must use `options[:key]` to retrieve the argument value.

It works here:

```
$thor example:events
since: 2 years ago

$ thor example:events --since="long time ago"
since: long time ago
```